# Accessing Ubuntu server via SSH alias- permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, alias

I have no problem accessing my Ubuntu server via an SSH command in my terminal. I have tried to set up an alias called `test` to save myself running the long command every single time, but when I run `test` I get a `Permission denied (publickey)` error.

However, if I literally copy and paste the command I have saved to my `test` alias, I can access the server from any directory. *Do aliases have different permissions than the actual commands themselves? How can I set up an alias to access my server via SSH?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using an alias, I used an ssh config instead. (Method 1: https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ssh-shortcut)

Now if I run `ssh test` I can access my server. A slight compromise, but I still got a similar desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a similar issue on ServerFault where the the problem was related to a **trailing whitespace** at the end of public key location.

Please checkout : https://serverfault.com/questions/251263/linux-ssh-config-alias-permission-denied-publickey

Comment: I did have a trailing whitespace but this did not solve the issue